# How can I show more details of one marker?

Tags: php, dictionary, associations, infowindow

**What I have:** 
The markers was created by a form submission, the form contains a postcode input. The below javascript will take this postcode and display as markers on google map. (this is a different page)

**page1.php** (code below)I have a php array, this array contains all infoWindow data and the javascript is to create map, markers and inforwindows.

```
<?php 
  ..............
  $info= array();
  foreach($details as $d) {
    $info[] = "<div id='infoData'>".$d['name'].$d['quantity']."<button id='details' onclick='window.location.href= \\\"page2.php\\\"'>Detail</button>"."<div>";
  }
  //.........
?>
```

The above code is everything on the infoWindow. Click that button in the products array will going to page2.php

```
<script>          
  //...................
  function init() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map");
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.528308,-0.3817765),
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);

    ///////////////add markers//////////
    var addressArray = ("abc", "def","xxx"), infoArray = (<?php echo $i; ?>);

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    for (var i = 0, j=addressArray.length; i < j; i++) {
      var info = infoArray[i];
      geocoder.geocode({'address': addressArray[i]}, createCallback(info, map));
    } //callback function
  }

  function createCallback(info, map) {
    var callback = function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            title: 'Click for more details'
        });
        //..................
   </script>
```

**What I want to achieve:** 
`page2.php`  I want to show more details of that `page1.php` button in `infowindow` I just clicked. How should I do this? Any hint??

I wrote php code on page two, but I just getting all records out, 
there's no associations between that marker just clicked and the page2 record. How can I achieve this? page two do not contain any map, just purely text data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you can pass a unique key or id of that record you want to show on page2.php and get that id using `$_GET` method and use to show details of that marker.

on page1.php

```
<?php 
  ..............
  $info= array();
  foreach($details as $d) {
    $info[] = "<div id='infoData'>".$d['name'].$d['quantity']."<button id='details' onclick='window.location.href= \\\"page2.php?marker=".$d['id']."\\\"'>Detail</button>"."<div>";
  }
  //.........
?>
```

on page2.php

```
$infomarker = $_GET['marker'];
```

Use `$infomarker` to get the all the details.

Comment: Thank you @Manjeet Barnala, you are a lifesaver.