# How to get individual data of postcode generated markers?

Tags: javascript, php, dictionary, postal-code

Note: I am sick of people mark it down without any comment! if you think this was a bad question please let me know why! This was not a school test, I am here to learn.

Update: I have a string of `array= array ("postcode1","postcode2","postcode3");` generates all markers on my google map and a single read button on each of the marker infowindow, how do I display the according information base on which marker I pressed?

All I can get now is the data of all postcodes, I know the reason is because of there wasn't a relation between what I queried out and the postcode.

Comment: Can you post some code that i can look at?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @JamesWaring please refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942722/how-can-i-show-more-details-of-one-marker-after-page-redirecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Manjeet Barnala again, all I need was to add an id for the button and use GET method to get the data.